# MongoDB space usage inefficiencies when using $push

Tags: mongodb

Let's say that I have two collections, A and B. Among other things, one of them (collection A) has an array whose cells contain subdocuments with a handful of keys.

I also have a script that will go through a queue (external to MongoDB), insert its items on collection B, and push any relevant info from these items into subdocuments in an array in collection A, using `$push`. As the script runs, the size of the documents in collection A grows significantly.

The problem seems to be that, whenever a document does not fit its allocated size, MongoDB will move it internally, but it *won't release the space it occupied previously*---new MongoDB documents won't use that space, not unless I run a `compact` or `repairDatabase` command.

In my case, the script seems to scorch through my disk space quickly. It inserts a couple of items into collection B, then tries to inserts into a document in collection A, and (I'm guessing) relocates said document without reusing its old spot. Perhaps this does not happen every time, with padding, but when these documents are about 10MB in size, that means that every time it *does* happen it burns through a significant chunk of the DB, even though the actual data size remains small. The process eats up my (fairly small, admittedly) DB in minutes.

Requiring a `compact` or `repairDatabase` command every time this happens is clumsy: there *is* space on disk, and I would like MongoDB to use it without requesting it explicitly. The alternative of having a separate collection for the subdocuments in the array would fix this issue, and is probably a better design anyway, but one that will require me to make joins that I wanted to avoid, this being one of the advantages of NoSQL.

So, first, does MongoDB actually use space the way I described above? Second, am I approaching this the wrong way? Perhaps there is a parameter I can set to get MongoDB to reuse this space automatically; if there is, is it advisable to use it? And third, are there other, more fitting, design approaches I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sammaye's recommendation was correct, but I needed to do some more digging to understand the cause of this issue. Here's what I found.

> So, first, does MongoDB actually use space the way I described above?

Yes, but that's not as intended. See bug [SERVER-8078](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8078), and its (non-obvious) duplicate, [SERVER-2958](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2958). Frequent `$push` operations cause MongoDB to shuffle documents around, and their old spots are not (yet!) reused without a `compact` or `repairDatabase` command.

> Second, am I approaching this the wrong way? Perhaps there is a parameter I can set to get MongoDB to reuse this space automatically; if there is, is it advisable to use it?

For some usages of `$push`, the `usePowerOf2Size` option initially consumes more memory, but stabilizes better (see the discussion on [SERVER-8078](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8078)). It may not work well with arrays that consistently tend to grow, which are a bad idea anyway because document sizes are capped.

> And third, are there other, more fitting, design approaches I'm missing?

If an array is going to have hundreds or thousands of items, or if its length is arbitrary but likely large, it's better to move its cells to a different collection, despite the need for additional database calls.

Comment: They are reused they just have to have a document that fits that position and when inserting a new document mongodb will only search like the first 100 entries of the freelists.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the questions you have asked you should have already known (Google searching would have brought up 100's of links including critical blog posts on the matter) having tried to use MongoDB in such a case however, this presentation should answer like 90% of your questions: http://www.mongodb.com/presentations/storage-engine-internals

As for solving the problem through settings etc, not really possible here, power of 2 sizes won't help for an array which grows like this. So to answer:

> Perhaps there is a parameter I can set to get MongoDB to reuse this space automatically; if there is, is it advisable to use it?

I would say no.

> And third, are there other, more fitting, design approaches I'm missing?

For something like this I would recommend using a separate collection to store each of the array elements as a new row independent of the parent document.

Comment: Thanks, Sammaye. For others stumbling upon the same problem: the 38 minute presentation linked above is very informative, but it does not address this issue at all. Also, most of the hundreds of links you get with a Google search are similarly irrelevant. See my answer for links to the relevant tickets at MongoDB's JIRA.